ISKCON does not read or preach the Vedas, but they always say they propagate Vedic culture. Why?
This is an irony. ISKCON does not read or preach the Vedas. The following three books they preach: are the Bhagavad Gita (part of Itihasa), Srimad Bhagavatam (Purana) and Chaitanya Caritamrita (the hagiography of their founder Sri Chaitanya). Srimad Bhagavatam is their main scripture.
So, they preach and propagate Puranic culture, not the Vedic culture. But all the time you will hear the term "Vedic" from them starting with Vedic culture, Vedic village, Vedic cooking, Vedic gurukul, and the temple of Vedic planetarium (which ironically depicts the universe as described in Srimad Bhagavatam).
They do not even read the Vedas. I have heard ISKCON monks saying that the Vedas have crores of verses, so it is clear that they have not read it. So, no wonder they do not preach it also, which is fine. But, then why do you call all the activities you do Vedic?

In Gaudiya Vaishnavism, Srimad Bhagavatam is considered to be the condensed essence of the entire Veda. From this point, they deem the study of the original Vaidika literature to be unnecessary.

@অনু Strange people. Strange logic.

Related: Why are the Vedas not the primary reference for most Hindus today?

Few people do study the Vedas today; that's just Kali Yuga for you.

@AmritenduMukhopadhyay Hello, Upanishadic verses do claim and/or insinuate the Ithihasa and Puranas as the fifth Veda. See Madhyandina-sruti, Brhad-aranyaka Upanishad 2.4.10 (asya mahato bhutasya nihsvasitam etad yad rg-vedo yajur-vedah sama vedo’tharvangirasa itihasah puranam ityadina); Atharva Veda: Gopatha Brahmana, purva 2.10 (evam ime sarva veda nirmitah sa-kalpah sa-rahasyah sa-brahmanah sopanisatkah setihasah sanvakhyatah sa-puranan); and Kauthumiya Chandogya Upanisad 7.1.4  ("nama va rg-vedo yajur-vedah sama-veda atharvanas caturtha itihasa-puranah pancamo vedanam vedah")

@AmritenduMukhopadhyay  Therefore, Puranic culture is Vedic culture, and vice versa. Citing and incorporating Puranic verses had existed prior to the rise of Gaudiya Vaishnavism. For instance consider the Vaishnava sampradayas like Shri Ramanuja's Shri Vaishavism, which focuses on the Vishnu Purana, and Shri Madhvacharya's Sad Vaishnavism, which stresses on the Shrimad Bhagavatam as well as the other Puranas (Vaishnavite and non-Vaishnavite like the Skanda). Calling Puranic culture different from Vedic culture is a newer trend and seeing they are synonymous is an older one.

@AmritenduMukhopadhyay All of the Vedas, including the Mahabharata Ithihasa and Puranas, have been compiled by Lord Ved Vyas and in my humble, but honest, opinion, all of His compilations should be treated on equal footing. Ishwara Paramatma is sarva sabdha vaacha, as per Shri Madhvacharya.

@Debbie Vyasa did not compose Vedas. Vedic Mantras were revealed to many Rishis. Their names are clearly written in the Vedas. Vedic Mantras are not revealed to Vyasa. Vyasa just divided Vedas into four parts. He composed Puranas and Itihasa. So you can not compare the Vedas and Puranas. Vedas are revelations, whereas Puranas are composed by human, (Vyasa, to be specific). This is a very basic concept in Hinduism.

@AmritenduMukhopadhyay Thank you for your comment. I never said Lord Ved Vyas composed the Vedas. I said He compiled them. To compile and to compose are very different things. The Vedas can indeed be compared to the Puranas. Did you not read the Chandogya Upanishad quote I cited which calls the Puranas and Ithihas the Fifth Veda? Did you not read the other Upanishadic verses I cited which juxtaposes the Rik, Sama, Yajur, Atbarvan and Ithihas/Purana? The side-by-side placement implies they are comparable.

@AmritenduMukhopadhyay That they are comparable also follows from simple logic. God, who is omniscient, knows at all times everything about the past, present, and future. Therefore He knows what everyone had said, is saying, and will be saying. Whether you accept Lord Ved Vyas to be God Himself is up to you, but regardless you must agree that God, who is the inner controller of everyone and the ultimate Doer, compiled from the infinite knowledge He has the words of the Rsis and their revelations (Upanishads, etc) and the events from the past (Puranas).

@AmritenduMukhopadhyay I know the Rsis names are in the Vedas. For instance, Sage Pippalada who is the teacher in the Prashna Upanishad is also mentioned in the Shaiva Puranas. His disciples in the Upanishad are also mentioned in the Ithihas. This shows that the Upanishads and the Puranas are linked and therefore the information in them are comparable and complementary

@AmritenduMukhopadhyay These are basic concepts of standard written English. Did you actually read what I cited? The verses I cited are from the texts you consider to solely be the Vedas.

@Debbie Lots of texts are called the fifth Veda—Ayurveda, Mahabharata, Bhagavata etc. Fifth Veda is like an honorary doctorate degree (You cannot get any academic privilege from it). This simply means the text is important. This title does not make the text really Veda. You have no understanding of Hinduism. Talking with you about Hinduism is a waste of time. Period.

@AmritenduMukhopadhyay The quote "Fifth Veda is alike an honorary doctorate degree...This title does not make the text really Veda" is just your hilarious opinion. Can you provide a pramana for your claim? The way you seemed to phrase your last comment seems to insinuate your belief that the Fifth Veda, though important, is like a second-class scripture that is not "really Veda."

@AmritenduMukhopadhyay If that were the case then according to your claim the Bhagavad Gita (part of the Mahbharata) is "like an honorary doctorate degree" and not "really Veda." Yet this is at odds with the Mahabharata itself. After narrating the Gita to King Janamejaya, Sage Vaishyampayan extolled the greatness of the Gita, Maa Ganga, and Lord Govinda and said knowing the Gita alone is enough to know the Vedic wisdom. It does not seem that the Sage is saying that Gita is not "really Veda" and is like "an honorary doctorate degree" from which "you cannot get any academic privilege."

@AmritenduMukhopadhyay The Sage indeed says you can get the ultimate privilege by learning the Gita spoken by Ishwara Paramatma Himself. Anyway, nice talking with you. :)
